# Embedded Wordpress form plugin shortcode not displaying in page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, ninja-forms

I currently creating a Wordpress custom theme with the Ninja Forms plugin, for one of the pages Ive embedded the Ninja Form using the shortcode such as  [ninja_form id=2] and Ive inserted the post directly into the inner page as such

```
$id = $_GET['page_id'];
$post = get_post($id, 'OBJECT', 'display');

//display the post
echo '<h1 class="dark">'.$post->post_title.'</h1>';
echo $post->post_content;
```

But the embedded form shortcode doesnt resolve to actually load the form into the page. What Im not doing??

Comment: Possibly the form JavaScript doesn't loads the content.

Answer (score 0):

try checking your Javascript files and CSS files that it doesn't affect the plugin you are using, because some of javascripts and JQueries overrides on the plugins you are using.